# Reading from file and putting data into JTable

Tags: java, swing, nullpointerexception, jtable, readfile

I have a text file which looks like this

```
---
*Jack
*James
Tim
*Hannah
Kim
```

I want my program to read each line of the file and get the names without the * and display it in a `JTable`. I have come up with the following code but it only displays the last name "Kim" in the table. Here is part of my code where the problem lies.

```
public class GUI extends JPanel{
public JFileChooser fileChooser;
public JButton openbtn;
public BufferedReader br;
public File file;

public GUI(){

    fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File(System.getProperty("user.home")));
    fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY);
    if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(openbtn)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){          
    String fName = null;

    file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
   try{
       br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
       String nextLine;    
       while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null)
       {
           if (nextLine.startsWith("---"))
           {
               String[] f = nextLine.split("*");
               fName = f[1];             
                   }
       }

      String[] columns = {"FirstName"};
      Object[][] data = {{fName}};
      JTable tableVIEW = new JTable(data, columns);
      tableVIEW.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(250, 35));
      tableVIEW.setFillsViewportHeight(true);               
        br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Error - INVALID FILE. PLEASE TRY AGAIN");
        }     
        }
    }
  }
```

So I tried to make the `fName` into an array and use a counter but I get this error when I browse for a file

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

And code:

```
    if (fileChooser.showOpenDialog(openbtn)==JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION){          
    String[] fName = null;
    int counter = 0;

    file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
   try{
       br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
       String nextLine;    
       while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null)
       {
           if (nextLine.startsWith("---"))
           {
               String[] f = nextLine.split("*");
               fName[counter] = f[1];             
               counter++;  
                   }
       }
```

How can I get all the entries (not just the last) in the table?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> it only displays the last name "Kim" in the Jtable

```
Object[][] data = {{fName}};
```

You only add one piece of information to the data array.

Instead you need to add each unique for of data to the TableModel. So first you create the DefaultTableModel (before reading data from the file) with code like:

```
String[] columns = {"FirstName"};
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(columns, 0);
```

Then in the loop whenever you read data from the file you add the data to the model:

```
Vector row = new Vector(1);
row.add( f[1] );      
model.addRow( row );
```

Then after the loop finishes you create the table:

```
JTable tableVIEW = new JTable(model);
```